# Convert Pixel to inch in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, pixel, dpi

How I can convert to pixel to inch, mm ,cm and [...to be continued...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size in Silverlight are in `DIU`, or *Device Independent Unit*. A `DIU` is a 96th of an inch. So, on a 96 DPI display (DPI = Dot Per Inch or Pixel Per Inch in this case), 1 `DIU` = 1 Pixel.